# how to determine the length of rotated text in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I am using canvas.stringWidth to calculate the length of sentence in reportlab.But when I rotate big statments it wrap text with the width calculated for straight one not for rotated one. Code snippet is

```
text_len = canvas.stringWidth("Hello" , "Helvetica", 10)
canvas.rotate(rotation)
P.drawOn(canvas, 0, 0)
```

It works fine for straight text but for rotated text it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `canvas.stringWidth(self, text, fontName, fontSize)` returns the width of the given string **without wrapping** it. So rotating the canvas will not decrease the width as the string is still the same length.

To show this lets look at the following example:

```
def rotated_text_length(c, string):
    text_len = c.stringWidth(string, "Helvetica", 10)
    print "Normal text: ", text_len

    c.rotate(90)
    text_len = c.stringWidth(string, "Helvetica", 10)
    print "Rotated text: ", text_len

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
rotated_text_length(c, "This is a very silly example"*100)
rotated_text_length(c, "This is a very silly example"*50)
```

If the string Width would wrap we would get the same length for both rotated sentences, yet the output is as follows:

```
Normal text:  11891.0
Rotated text:  11891.0
Normal text:  5945.5
Rotated text:  5945.5
```

Which indicates that the returned width only depends on the string length (and of course font). So no wrapping is applied which makes sense based on the Reportlab reference:

> `def stringWidth(self, text, fontName=None, fontSize=None):`
>
> gets width of a string in the given font and size

Comment: I understand this but if we want to write rotated text suppose by 45 degree then available space to write is more than the plane writing....my logic is to use rotated_length = stringWidth/cos(rotation angle)

Comment: In that case you might one to check this link out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reportlab-users/jn0F1PI8R2g

Comment: Thanx for the link...It was useful